# Finding the value of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What is the value of 
$ (1/(1.3.5)) + 1/(3.5.7) + 1/(5.7.9) + 1/(7.9.11) + 1/(9.11.13) $

$a.)$ $ 70/249 $
$b.)$ $ 53/249 $
$c.)$ $ 73/440 $
$d.)$ $ 1/18 $

My approach : I tried to simplify the above expression by writing out the general term $ (2*n-1)(2*n+1)(2*n+3) $ and then posed the question as a summation of this from 1 to n. Afterwards to add these up I tried to use partial fractions hoping that some of the terms would cancel out. But to no avail.

Please tell me, if my mistake is in partial fractions ( and show how they cancel out ) or tell me a better way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\dfrac8{(m-2)m(m+2)}=2\cdot\dfrac{m+2-(m-2)}{(m-2)m(m+2)}=\dfrac2{(m-2)m}-\dfrac2{(m+2)m}$$

$$=\left(\dfrac1{m-2}-\dfrac1m\right)-\left(\dfrac1m-\dfrac1{m+2}\right)$$

$$=f(m)-f(m+2)$$

where $f(r)=\dfrac1{r-2}-\dfrac1r$

Do you recognize the Telescoping nature?

Comment: Could tell me more about what restrictions are you placing on m ?

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava, A finite integer, right? Can you find $n$ in the question?

Comment: Yeah I could sort of find what you were telling me about , so what you are considering to be m it actually is 2n+1 according to my formulation of the problem , mentioned above. 

Though I am still trying to figure out how exactly does the telescoping nature of the series work

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava, Yes $m=2n+1$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Yep , I got it now thank you so much